# Understand this proof of division with remainder

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, divisibility, euclidean-algorithm

I'm a very newbie, even if I studied some math at college... Now I'm trying to study *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra"*, by J.A. Gallian but I'm already facing some difficulties trying to understand the proof of the very first theorem (0.1) about the division algorithm.

The theorem says:

> Let a and b be integers with $b > 0$. Then there exist unique integers
> q and r with the property that $a=bq + r$, where $0\le r\le b$

Trying to prove the existence part of the theorem, the author writes:

> Consider the set $S =\{a - bk |\  k\text{ is an integer and }a - bk\ge 0\}$.
> If $0\in S$, then $b$ divides $a$ and we may obtain the desired result with $q =\tfrac ab$ and $r = 0$. Now assume $0\notin S$. Since $S$ is nonempty [if $a > 0$ then $a - b\times0\in S$ and if $a < 0$ then $a - b(2a) = a(1 - 2b) \in S$; and $a\neq0$ since $0\notin S$]...

Ok, my question is: why author put $k = 2a$ when explain why S is non empty with $a < 0$? Where does this $k = 2a$ come from? Why can't be $k=a$, for example?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can take also $k=a$, but then if $b=1$ then $a-kb=0$ and you assumed that $0\not \in S$. Hence he took $k=2a$ in order to get a sharp inequality $a-bk>0$.

Comment: I think that your $E$'s should be $\in$ (in LaTeX \in), is that correct?

Comment: Yes you're right, I'm sorry I'm still not so good at using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author chose $k=2a$ because for the most obvious choice $k=a$ there is a problem: If $b=1$ then $a-b\times a=0$, which is not in $S$.

For $k=2a$ we have $a-b\times2a=a(1-2b)\in S$ because certainly $1-2b<0$. So this does show that $S$ is nonempty.